# SQL to transpose data

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table named Forecast as below:

[image]

Product_BK has about 80,000 records, while the Month has 12. The States remain static at 5.

How can I write a query to transpose the data to look like below:

[image]

This is on a SQL server and prefer not to go down the dynamic query route.

Thank you for all your inputs

Comment: This looks to me like you want to _unpivot_ the original table.  What database are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, etc.).  This would be relatively painless in Oracle or SQL Server, but harder in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tim, this is on MS SQL server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL Server's built-in [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_BK, Month, State, Forecast
FROM
(SELECT * FROM Forecast_Table) t
UNPIVOT
(Forecast FOR State IN (SA_NT, QLD, VIC_TAS, WA, NSW_ACT)) AS fcst
```

Comment: It worked like magic! You are an absolute STAR. Thanks so much for the quick response again.

Comment: Already did, but I don't have enough Brownie points to be displayed :)

Comment: Two more questions based on the suggested query: How can I rename the default States (eg: QLD to Quensland) as an output from the query? How can I aggregate the states' forecast to a higher level (eg: National)? Thank you

Comment: You can alias the states as whatever you want, and you can aggregate the states as well.  You should open a new question.

Comment: New question opened...Thanks