# Aggregate and alias on UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

How can I rename (alias) the default States (eg: QLD to Quensland) as an output from the below query? 
Also how can I aggregate (SUM) the states' forecast to a higher level (eg: National)?

```
SELECT PRODUCT_BK, Month, State, Forecast
FROM
(SELECT * FROM Forecast_Table) t
UNPIVOT
(Forecast FOR State IN (SA_NT, QLD, VIC_TAS, WA, NSW_ACT)) AS fcst
```

Thank you

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478749/sql-to-transpose-data/40478918?noredirect=1#comment68244588_40478918).

Comment: What actual aggregation do you want?  Can you show expected output?

Comment: Figured out myself, thanks heaps for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `case` for such purposes

```
SELECT PRODUCT_BK,
       MONTH,
       CASE [State] WHEN 'QLD' THEN 'Quensland'
                    WHEN 'SA_NT' THEN 'something else'
                    ELSE [State]
       END AS [State],
       Forecast
FROM (SELECT * FROM Forecast_Table) t 
UNPIVOT (Forecast FOR State IN (SA_NT, QLD, VIC_TAS, WA, NSW_ACT)) AS fcst
```

or, as alternative way, you can create `#temp_table` or  `@variable_table` or table in your db, fill this table with old & new names and join final output with this table.

example:

```
-- create variable table to store reference between old and new alias
DECLARE @Sometable AS TABLE
    (
      OldName NVARCHAR(10) ,
      ShouldBeName NVARCHAR(20)
    )
INSERT  @Sometable
        ( OldName, ShouldBeName )
VALUES  ( 'SA_NT', 'Some Name 1' ),
        ( 'QLD', 'Some Name 2' ),
        ( 'VIC_TAS', 'Some Name 3' );

--final query
SELECT  fcst.PRODUCT_BK ,
        fcst.Month ,
        COALESCE(S.ShouldBeName, fcst.[State]) AS [State] ,
        fcst.Forecast
FROM    ( SELECT * FROM Forecast_Table ) t
        UNPIVOT ( Forecast FOR State IN ( SA_NT, QLD, VIC_TAS, WA, NSW_ACT ) ) AS fcst
        LEFT JOIN @Sometable AS S ON fcst.[State] = S.OldName
```

Or, even like this:

```
SELECT  fcst.PRODUCT_BK ,
        fcst.Month ,
        COALESCE(S.ShouldBeName, fcst.[State]) AS [State] ,
        fcst.Forecast
FROM    ( SELECT * FROM Forecast_Table ) t 
        UNPIVOT ( Forecast FOR State IN ( SA_NT, QLD, VIC_TAS, WA, NSW_ACT ) ) AS fcst
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    ( VALUES ( 'SA_NT', 'Some Name 1' ), 
                                     ( 'QLD', 'Some Name 2' ),
                                     ( 'VIC_TAS', 'Some Name 3' ) 
                             ) AS S ( OldName, ShouldBeName ) 
                   ) AS S ON fcst.[State] = S.OldName
```

Comment: Thanks Vasily, the first option worked nice and easy. I have also figured out to aggregate the forecast at a national level. Your effort is much appreciated.