# How to Unpivot with multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Below is my table structure. i wants to unpivot below data.

```
amount  user    amount1 user1   amount2 user2   amount3 user3   amount4 user4
10      1       20      2       30      3       40      4       50      5
```

Now i wants result as below.

```
amount user
10     1
20     2
30     3
40     4
50     5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to transpose data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478749/sql-to-transpose-data)

Comment: you can use `unpivot` or `union select`. Maybe the easiest is `select amount, user from table1 union select amount1, user1 from table1`

Answer (score 0):

You want to unpivot the data.  I recommend `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.amount, t.user),
             (t.amount1, t.user1),
             (t.amount2, t.user2),
             (t.amount3, t.user3),
             (t.amount4, t.user4)
     ) v(amount, user);
```

Comment: it's Done but need unpivot query.

Comment: @KCS . . . I much prefer this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following it will work for your specific case here:

```
SELECT 'user' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY 1 ORDER BY amountx) AS VARCHAR) AS [user],amountx
FROM [table]
UNPIVOT(
amountx 
FOR amntx IN (amount,amount1,amount2,amount3,amount4)

) AS UP
```

http://rextester.com/EWXV86982